# How to call a non static variable from another class in Android?

Tags: java, android

Please understand that I have just started coding for less than a week now and I have never made an app or a program before. I just look on the internet on how to do things and try to mix everything. 
So I am making an android app, and I need to get the notification from a mysql database.
What I did is that I found a php script that converts the data in the mysql tables to a Json format so that I can read it with my app.
Below is the part where I display the data:
Mysql_display.java:

```
    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] licences = new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            licences[i] = obj.getString("licence_number");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, licences);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
```

What I want is to display this information (licences) on the notification also:
MainActivity.java

```
    public void displayNotification(){


        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm)
                        .setContentTitle("Title")
                        .setContentText("Licences")
                        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                ;

        NotificationManagerCompat mNotifMgr = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        mNotifMgr.notify( 1, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

Comment: if you are coding for less than a week, you should start with learning the basics. either it is static and you can call it through the class, or it's not static, and  can only be called through an instance of the class

Comment: I learn what I have to learn depending on what project's phase I am in

Comment: @Amine I'm talking about what you should have learned at least a year before considering starting a project.

Answer (score -1):

You just can't. In order to access directly a variable from another class, a variable must be declared static, otherwise the only way is creating an oject and reference it like myObject.variableName.